# ruby 1.8 prime succ algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, primes

I've searched every site I can imagine and am unable to determine the base algorithm that ruby 1.8 uses to create a list of primes in the Prime class under mathn.  The following is a runnable version of the succ method, called 100 times (in order to find the 100th prime).  Does anyone know how this works?

```
number_of_primes = 100

seed = 1
primes = Array.new
counts = Array.new


while primes.size < number_of_primes
  i = -1
  size = primes.size
  while i < size
    if i == -1
      seed += 1
      i += 1
    else
      while seed > counts[i]
        counts[i] += primes[i]
      end
      if seed != counts[i]
        i += 1
      else
        i = -1
      end
    end
  end
  primes.push seed
  counts.push (seed + seed)
end

puts seed
```

The actual code is of course: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/mathn/rdoc/Prime.html

It doesn't look like a sieve algorithm as there is no predefined list to sift through, it's not a trial division algorithm as there are no division or modulus operations.  I'm totally stumped.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear, not sure why you got the downvotes and the close votes.

Comment: I don't mind getting downvoted if I've done something stupid/posted something unclear.  It would be nice, however, if people who cast the downvotes let me know why so that I could fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm is based on the sieve of Eratosthenes.

`seed` is the integer being tested for primeness. `primes` is the list of primes smaller than `seed` and `counts` holds the corresponding smallest multiple that is greater than `seed`.

Think of `counts` as the list of the "next" crossed out numbers, but only one per prime, constantly updated. When finding the next largest multiple, if we get exactly `seed`, then it's not a prime, so it resets the outer loop (with `i=-1`).

Only when we've updated the list of greater multiples, without encountering exactly `seed`, can we deduce that `seed` is prime.

Here's the code slightly simplified and commented:

```
number_of_primes = 100

seed = 1
primes = []
counts = []

while primes.size < number_of_primes
  seed += 1
  i = 0
  while i < primes.size      # For each known prime
    while seed > counts[i]   # Update counts to hold the next multiple >= seed
      counts[i] += primes[i] # by adding the current prime enough times
    end
    if seed != counts[i]
      i += 1    # Go update next prime
    else
      i = 0     # seed is a multiple, so start over...
      seed += 1 # with the next integer
    end
  end
  # The current seed is not a multiple of any of the previously found primes, so...
  primes.push seed
  counts.push (seed + seed)
end

puts seed
```

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate your help and the clarity of your explanation.  It still took me a second to fully understand what was happening, but I've got it now.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been wondering about that algorithm for years -- with your explanation, it finally makes sense.